# ColdFusion 11 installation unsuccessful

Tags: iis, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I installed ColdFusion 11 Developer version (downloaded from Adobe site 3 months trial) on Windows 8.1 and IIS7. I got this error when trying to open the ColdFusion administrator (see below). Is there a step by step example on how to fix this?

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
Detailed Error Information:
Module         CustomErrorModule
Notification   SendResponse
Handler        cfmHandler
Error Code     0x800700b7
Config Error   Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'mimeMap' with unique key attribute 'fileExtension' set to '.air'
Config File    \localhost\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config
Requested URL  localhost:80/administrator/CFIDE/index.cfm
Physical Path  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\administrator\CFIDE\index.cfm
Logon Method   Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous
Config Source:
      4: <staticContent>
      5:  <mimeMap fileExtension=".air" mimeType="application/vnd.adobe.air-
            application-installer-package+zip" />
      6: </staticContent>
```

Comment: seems like you have a duplicate mime entry go to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config file and comment out the mime mapping for .air

Comment: The error message is pretty explicit. Does your config file have duplicate entries for `mimeMap fileExtension=".air"` ?  The config file is here - `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config` (from the error message).

Comment: Better suited for Server Fault.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the MIME type from web.config

`<mimeMap fileExtension=".air" mimeType="application/vnd.adobe.air-application-installer-package+zip" />` and save the file. Restart IIS and that should fix the issue.

Comment: I restarted IIS and I still get error, this time it says:<br> 
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error<br>
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.<br> Detailed Error Information:<br>Module    IsapiModule<br>Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler<br>Handler    cfmHandler<br>Error Code    0x800700c1<br>Requested URL    http://127.0.0.1:80/MyApp/index.cfm<br>Physical Path    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\index.cfm<br>Logon Method    Anonymous<br>Logon User    Anonymous

Comment: Do you have permissions on your webroot and subsequent folders.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well after updating Coldfusion 11 to the upgrade 2 (patch),
somehow it reads web.config file under C:\Coldfusion11\cfusion\wwwroot
What I did was simply rename the web.config to something like web - error.config
IIS will skip this file and run just fine.
When the file exists, I couldn't even access MIME configuration from the IIS Manager, so removal or rename of that file was the solution for me.
It's also discussed in : http://blog.immanuelnoel.com/2014/09/22/busting-the-http-error-500-19-on-coldfusion-11-iis/ and probably a bug under initial coldfusion configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the mime type from the web.config was enough and its remaining content was all right in our case; please note that this was related to the ColdFusion sites in general and not with the ColdFusion Administrator. The problem started after upgrading from ColdFusion 10 (update level 11) to 11 (update level 0) (on IIS 7.5, Windows Server 2008 R2), having changed the connectors from old version to ColdFusion 11 (as the installation document indicates at "Verify your IIS configuration" section). It had two positive effects:

- the cascading styles started being delivered correctly
- the 500 Internal Error on the IIS "Windows Authentication" directories stopped appearing (we regarded also https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1031711)

Answer (score 0):

Was it an upgrade?  I had a similar problem.  I had to manually disable my Coldfusion 9 handlers.
If your previous Coldfusion handlers are still active, and you don't want to remove them until you are confident 11 is stable you can deactivate them in the **web.config** file.

```
<handler>
  <remove name="AboMapperCustom-somenumber"  />    
  <remove name="AboMapperCustom-anothernumber"  /> 
</handler>
```

The web.config file should be found in the root directory of each website.

Answer (score 0):

```
This solved it for me, add <remove fileExtension=".air" /> like the following to web.config:

<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".air" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".air" mimeType="application/vnd.adobe.air-application-installer-package+zip" />
</staticContent>
```